# How to download the generated CSV file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tailwind-css

I am trying to download the CSV file processed by the ReportExport service, in the logs the sent data is a "Sent data Business analyst-report-2022-12-12.csv". But the file is not downloaded remotely.
reports_controller.rb

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def export
    status = HoursUploader.new(params[:hours_file]).call
    return redirect_to reports_path, alert: status if status != TasksUploader::OK

    total_hours = Hour.last
    status = HoursDistributor.new(total_hours).call
    return redirect_to reports_path, alert: status if status != HoursDistributor::OK

    send_data ReportExport.new(total_hours).to_csv, filename: "#{total_hours.position_english}-report-#{Time.zone.today}.csv", content_type: 'text/csv'
  end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with url: export_reports_path, method: :post do |f| %>
  <form action="#" class="space-y-7">
    <div class="mt-3">
      <%= f.label :hours_file, class: "block my-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300"%>
      <%= f.file_field :hours_file, direct_upload: 'false', class: "block w-full p-1.5 text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 cursor-pointer dark:text-gray-400 focus:outline-none dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400" %>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="mt-10 flex w-full items-center justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-indigo-600 py-3 px-8 text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2">
      <%= f.submit "Create" %>
    </button>
  </form>
<% end %>
```

ReportExport generates the required CSV file

I added data: {turbolinks: false}, disposition: attachment,  did submit with a link and a button but it didn't help. Also it worked before I added styles.

```
<%= form_with url: export_reports_path, method: :post do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :hours_file, "Hours" %>
  <%= form.file_field :hours_file %>
  <%= form.button "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

How do I fix the error? Thank you in advance!

Comment: To fix the error, you can try the following steps:

    1.Make sure that the send_data method is called inside the export action in the ReportsController. This will ensure that the CSV file is actually sent to the client.

    2. Add the :disposition option to the send_data method to specify that the file should be downloaded by the client. For example:

`send_data ReportExport.new(total_hours).to_csv, filename: "#{total_hours.position_english}-report-#{Time.zone.today}.csv", content_type: 'text/csv', disposition: 'attachment'`

Comment: Yes, it processing by ReportsController#export (POST 'reports/export'). I tried adding disposition: 'attachment', but it says in the documentation that the send_data method by default has this value